# here document and double backslash

Tags: bash, shell

If I use a here document in a shell script that contains multiple backslashes '\', the shell translates it into a single backslash. Can I work around this without changing the text ?

```
$ cat <<EOF  
> Print \\hello \\world  
> EOF  
Print \hello \world
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Quote the beginning here document marker:

```
cat <<'EOF'
Print \\hello \\world
EOF
```

Comment: Works. Apparently I cannot accept the answer until after 11 min !

Comment: Section 3.6.6 at http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections explains *why* this answer works.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to what Dennis mentions The command `sed` can also take care of this.

```
sed 's/\\/\\\\/g' <<EOF
Print \\hello \\world
EOF
```